# Get the average for each 4 rows

Tags: r

I have a column with hundreds of values, I want to get the average for each 4 rows, then I move to another four rows, etc. How could I write that loop in R studio, I attached here a simple example, what should I do if I have `NA` values, how to consider those values as zeros?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: `colMeans(matrix(x, nrow = 4), na.rm = TRUE)` is fast and simple.